# Swift - Removing specific spawned enemy

Tags: ios, swift

My code currently spawns a new enemy every second so there are multiple spawned enemies on the screen at the same time.  I am able to detect a collision but I cannot figure out how to detect which enemy was hit so that I can remove it from the screen.  Currently when a collision occurs and I remove the node from the screen, the last spawn enemy is removed and not the specific enemy that was hit. Any ideas on how to detect which spawned enemy was hit?

Comment: Which game engine do you use?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you're using SpriteKit?

When you create a new enemy, you should give it a name. To do this, do `enemyChildNode.name = "enemy"`. Then, when a collision is detected, use `enumerateChildNodesWithName` to check which node has collided.

This is how you declare this method:

```
func enumerateChildNodesWithName(_ name: String,
                  usingBlock block: ((SKNode!,
                                      UnsafeMutablePointer<ObjCBool>) -> Void)!)
```

For more information on this go [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKNode_Ref/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/SKNode/enumerateChildNodesWithName:usingBlock:).

So, you should use it like this:

```
 enumerateChildNodesWithName("enemy") { node, stop in
        let enemy = node as! SKSpriteNode
        //check if enemy is being hit
        //if true: enemy.removeFromParent()
    }
```

I hope this helps you out!

Comment: Thanks for your help.  I was able to figure this out using the logic used in your example.

Answer (score 1):

Loads of ways to achieve this, one of the easiest is to have your enemy-sprites, but in my mind the easiest is to use the `contactDelegate` for your scene's `physicsWorld`.

In `didBeginContact(contact: SKPhysicsContact)` you can get the two colliding nodes by accessing `contact.bodyA.node` & `contact.bodyB.node`. Then your enemyNodes only need to have a `wasHit()` function which runs a `removeFromParent` action. (Implemented either trough subclassing or an extension).

Now, you probably need some logic to sort out the different types involved in the collission, but you have the options of checking on both class-type and `categoryBitMasks`.